# How to implement two-factor authentication in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire, two-factor-authentication

I am new to Spotfire. I am trying to implement two factor authentication for Spotfire Web player login. The instructions provided on Spotfire support portal is not specific. Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only form of two-factor authentication that is supported out-of-the-box would be the combination of some standard authentication method (such as plain username/password) with X.509 client certificates (which could be stored on smart cards or such).

Another option could be to utilize some external authentication provider (typically using OpenID Connect) and configure two-factor authentication there.

Comment: Thank you. I have achieved this with Open ID connect.